# OPC DA android sdk/driver

Tags: android, sdk, opc

I'm looking into the possibility of using android tablet with Human Machine Interface (HMI) of process control system. Have someone implemented OPC DA sdk/driver for android framework?

Answer (score 2):

Technically and theoretically, implementing OPC DA on Android is possible, but I this that nobody has done it, and nobody ever will. The reason for it is that the implementer would have to write the whole DCOM protocol stack (and RPC, which it is based upon). Microsoft has (after some lawsuit) published these protocols, therefore nothing prevents it. But they are extremely large and complicated. Earlier attempts to do similar (e.g. on Linux) have not really succeeded either.

I suggest that your switch you thinking to more modern OPC UA (Unified Architecture), which is based on Web services, and is not dependent on Microsoft protocols.

Comment: I wouldn't say that OPC-UA is based on web services (nobody uses opc.http endpoints)... but you're right that he should be thinking about using OPC-UA instead of OPC-DA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is outdated, but I think it could help:

Opc UA seems promising, however you can write your own proxy on Windows to access OPC DA server from Android via this application.

I developed C# application which connects to OPC DA server and forwards the data to REST API, which is pretty easy to access from Android(with Retrofit, for example).

Code is available on my github [repository](https://github.com/Marchuck/OPC_DA_Proxy/).